Shell/terminal no longer registers premature input text
Suppose I'm waiting for a long running command to complete.
Before I was able to type the 2nd command, and the entered text would be preserved when the 1st command completed and the prompt returned (and would even execute the 2nd command if I had pressed enter).
This no longer happens and I don't remember updating zsh, iTerm Mac OS client or anything in my Ubuntu Server.
I'm not sure what to Google for, I can't quite think what search terms to use. And my tags may be misleading. I hope someone can point me in the right direction
Example A: 2nd Command executed
Desired
$ sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/media/me/disk pool_my/disk
(long pause)sudo chown me /media/me/disk<enter>
$ ls -ld /media/me/disk
drwxr-xr-x 2 me me 2 Sep 18 21:37 /media/sarnobat/videos_10G

Actual
$ sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/media/me/disk pool_my/disk
(long pause)sudo chown me:me /media/me/disk<enter>
$ ls -ld /media/me/disk
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 2 Sep 18 21:37 /media/sarnobat/videos_10G

The 2nd command wasn't executed.
Example B: 2nd command text preserved
Desired
$ sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/media/me/disk pool_my/disk
(long pause)sudo chown me /med
$ sudo chown me /med

Actual
$ sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/media/me/disk pool_my/disk
(long pause)sudo chown me /med
$ 

The incomplete command I began typing before the previous command finished is gone.

Does it happen with any command as the first command? What if the first command is a sleep 60 or sudo sleep 60? It could be sudo or zfs that eats all its pending input before quitting, just like e.g. apt or apt-get does (much to my dislike) -- or wait, now that I'm thinking about it, is it perhaps sudo and not apt-get? :) -- wow, looks like I've figured out something new, it's indeed sudo and not apt-get eating the pending input.

I think you’re right about sudo. I’ll keep my eyes open (maybe reconsider blindly using sudo in some of my other frequent commands). Thanks for preserving the inner dialogue - this is how we really arrive at answers :)

It's sudo that eats the premature input.
Its use_pty option (in sudoers) was recently switched to be enabled by default, to prevent CVE-2005-4890-like attacks. I assume your system received this change recently, causing the change in behavior.
With use_pty there needs to be a process running (sudo itself, or a fork thereof) which keeps forwarding data back and forth between the "host" and the "guest" tty. This design necessarily means that anything you type is immediately consumed and forwarded to whatever is running under sudo. If that process quits without consuming it, it's lost. Eating your input is not a deliberate decision of sudo, but a necessary side effect of this design.
You can revert to the old behavior of not allocating a new tty. In that case sudo doesn't consume premature input. However, you might be subject to attacks involving ioctl(TIOCSTI), something that's nowadays getting obsoleted and removed from Linux systems (I'm not sure about macOS, though).
As far as I understand, depending on your system, the security issue may or may not be a valid one. If user X performs a sudo to user Y, it's possible for a malicious app, supposedly running as user Y, to have a bad effect on user X which we don't want to happen. In this scenario it's an actual threat.
Presumably on quite a few single-user systems the sole purpose of sudo is to run some selected tools with elevated (root) privileges, and in that case if the said tool is malicous then all bets are already lost. In this case it's just opening another door where many doors are already open. In such a setup I'd feel comfortable disabling the use_pty option. Disclaimer: I take no responsibility. ( Update: see also https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/338 )
Thanks a lot for asking this question! I've been annoyed for many-many years by sudo apt-get consuming premature input, and now you triggered me to investigate and understand what's going on :)

Great info, way more than I thought about.
